# Cloud or server based connection to display data on user device from the server or cloud services

Tags: server, cloud

there I want to build an android app which must get some information from a online server and then display over the mobile app of user , can anyone please guide me what should I do for updating these details, will I have to make a separate a server to get data back and forth or I should use some cloud services to do the same.

Comment: See [ask]. This site is not a place where someone will design your app for you. The idea is that you give it a try yourself and come back when you have a specific coding question.

Comment: @jdv hi there,thanks for help :) , but i am not asking someone to design my app, I can learn and solve any coding problem on my own, but as I do not have any networking information, I just want information or guidance for technology or method which I should use, rest I will do myself. Please let me know what method I should use, you just tell the name and coding or rest I will learn and do it by myself.I know I sound like an idiot, but boss you are highly intelligent and have more experience than me.

Comment: Hi there @jdv, I think I have got my answer, this is in response to my question asked. If there are other peoples like me then this answer is for them. Please use server client based technique using java. For more you can search google, or you can just let me know as I am learning and creating the same for myself and also post the codes for it.

Comment: That's all well and good, but, strictly speaking, this question is too broad for [SO].